# OneSignal Push Notification Unsubscribe user Android

Tags: java, android, onesignal, unsubscribe

I have successfully implemented push notification for my android app using OneSignal. I have implemented a checkbox in settings to enable user to opt out from receiving notifications.
I passed OneSignal.setSubscription(false); but it is having no effect whatsoever and I am still able to receive notifications. Any pointers are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are initialising onesignal properly.
Check if the checkbox selected value is true/false.Or try setting `OneSignal.setSubscription(false)` and check.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying.I have initialized it correctly using this
OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init(); 
and the checkbox is working correctly, i have tested it with a toast too.

Answer (score 0):

It's really weird why it didn't work for 100 times i tried yesterday and now it started working with the same code :/